# MySQLi & mysql_real_escape_string() Giving me a bunch of errors

Tags: string, mysqli, escaping

Im having problem with my UPDATE code., since i'm new at php, im trying to figure out what's been the prolem with my UPDATE command here's my line of code. My insert and delete commands are good to go but this one gives me a headache for 4 hours now.

```
<?php
            
            include 'includes/conn.php';
            if($_POST){
                    //write query
                    $sql = "UPDATE 
                                            member 
                                    SET
                                            fname = ?, 
                                            lname = ?,
                                            mname = ?,
                                            email = ?,
                                            address = ?,
                                            gender = ?,
                                            contact = ?,
                                            email = ?,
                                            username = ?,
                                            password  = ?
                                    WHERE 
                                            mem_id = ?";

                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param(
                            'sssssssssi', 
                            $_POST['fname'], 
                            $_POST['lname'],
                            $_POST['mname'],
                            $_POST['email'],
                            $_POST['address'],
                            $_POST['gender'],
                            $_POST['contact'],                              
                            $_POST['username'],
                            $_POST['password'],
                            $_POST['mem_id']
                    );


                    if($stmt->execute()){
                            echo "User was updated.";
                            $stmt->close();
                    }else{
                            die("Unable to update.");
                    }
            }
                         $sql = "SELECT 
                                fname, lname, mname, email, address, gender, contact,    username, password, mem_id
                        FROM 
                                member
                        WHERE 
                                mem_id = \"" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['mem_id']) . "\"
                        LIMIT 
                                0,1";

                        $result = $mysqli->query( $sql );

                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                        extract($row);

                        $result->free();
                        $mysqli->close();
                        ?>
```

hope you guys could help o by the way it gives me this error

> Undefined index: mem_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\prjTheVillagePlaygroup\execute_editmenu.php on line 134
>
> Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prjTheVillagePlaygroup\execute_editmenu.php on line 141

Comment: The number of placeholders in your query doesn't match the number of parameters you're using in `$stmt->bind_param()`. You are using `email` twice in your query.

Comment: iStimple so sorry about the post, still got no sleep with this one. :( Krister Andersson, already checked it and removed the extra email but still no clue about the error it was giving to me.

Comment: Sir mseifert but already removed it but still the error goes on with the line 
**Undefined index: mem_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\prjTheVillagePlaygroup\execute_editmenu.php on line 134
Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prjTheVillagePlaygroup\execute_editmenu.php on line 141**

Comment: The error always triggers on this part --> 
mem_id = \"" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['mem_id']) . "\"
Thanks for all the help.!

Comment: You are using `$_GET['mem_id']` where it should likely be `$_POST['mem_id']` - all your other variables are set with `$_POST`

Comment: Also, if you wish for me to be notified of your message you need to respond to my post below or try addressing my name as so: `@mseifert`. I've updated my post below will additional information.

Comment: @mseifert sorry for the inconvenience im giving you., i tried and deleted the email, then put the if condition to the syntax i made, and still the error triggers on this part --> 
 mem_id = \"" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['mem_id']) . "\"

the error tells that Undefined index in mem_id and another is 
extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given 
thank you for your time answering my problem.. I really do appreciate it.,

Comment: Insert a var_dump($_POST) to see what you have coming from your form. Fix what's off about mem_id. It may be missing or spellled wrong. Post back your results.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
email = ?
```

listed twice in the update statement. Delete the second one.

Note that your binding does not have to change. It will have the correct number of parameters after the deletion.

Also, you are using `$_GET['mem_id']` where it should likely be `$_POST['mem_id']` - all your other variables are set with `$_POST`

With regard to `Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`, this is due to the query failing.

Check for the $result to make sure the query succeeded and what the error is:

```
$result = $mysqli->query( $sql );
if (!$result) 
    printf("Error: " . mysqli->error); // or use die("Error: " . mysqli->error)
}


$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
extract($row);
```